# How to find maximum (not with numbers,but with parameters) of 2-variables function under constraints?

Tags: maximum

I have these functions:

```
f[dA_,dB_] :=(3.2 (0.389 +dA (-2 (0.175 + 0.012 dB) + 0.078 (-1 + dB) +0.012 (-1 + dB)^2) + dA^2 (0.214 - 0.027 dB) - 0.039 (-1 + dA) (-1 + dB)^2 + (-0.027 + 0.175 (-2 + dB)) dB) + (-1 + dA) (-1 + dB) (2.04 (-1 + dA) (-1 + dB) + (-1 + dA dB) Vin))/((-1 + dA) (-1 + dB) (-1 + dA dB) Vin)
g[dA_,dB_] :=-3.2 (0.214/(1 - dA) + (0.187 dA)/(1 - dA)^2) + ((1 - (1.02 (1 - dA))/Vin) Vin)/(1 - dA)
h[dA_,dB_] :=-3.2 (0.214/(1 - dB) + (0.187 dB)/(1 - dB)^2) + (dB (1 - (1.02 (1 - dB))/(dB Vin)) Vin)/(1 - dB)
```

I would like to find the maximum of `f`, with parameter `Vin`. Also, the following constraints must be met:

```
0<dA<1 && 0<dB<1 && 0<Vin<=625 && g+h=625
```

I have been trying to use the function `FindMaximum`, but I think I do something wrong and I don't have any solution.

```
FindMaximum[{f, 0 < dA < 1 && 0 < dB < 1 && 0 < Vin <= 625 && g + h=625},{dA, dB}]
```

Could somebody help me understand what is my mistake or suggest another way to solve my problem? I have been also trying to use Partial Differential Equations, but I didn't have results also there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give numeric values to `Vin`.

This:

```
max = Table[{dA, dB} /. 
   FindMaximum[{f[dA, dB], 
      0 < dA < 1 && 0 < dB < 1 && g[dA, dB] + h[dA, dB] == 625},
        {{dA, 1/2}, {dB, 1/2}}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"][[2]], {Vin, 1, 625}]
```

or better this:

```
max = Table[
   FindArgMax[{f[dA, dB], 
     0 < dA < 1 && 0 < dB < 1 && g[dA, dB] + h[dA, dB] == 625},
      {{dA, 1/2}, {dB, 1/2}}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"], {Vin, 1, 625}];
```

shows that the maximum is along the line `dA = dB` for all `Vin`:

```
ListPlot[max, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> {"dA", "dB"}]
```

[image]

To verify:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[dA, dB] /. Vin -> v0, {dA, 0, 1}, {dB, 0, 1}],
  {{v0, 100}, 1, 625, Appearance -> {"Open"}}]
```

[image]

```
c = max[[100]]
```

> {0.731275, 0.731275}

```
f @@ c /. Vin -> 100
```

> 0.970111

```
(g @@ c + h @@ c) /. Vin -> 100
```

> 625.

```
f[0.5, 0.5] /. Vin -> 100
```

> 0.976091

Comment: Thank you very much for the analytical and quick answer. Indeed, I am expecting dA=dB for all Vin. However, is there a way to have the analytical solution, e.g. dA=function(Vin), dB=function(Vin)?

Comment: [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) doesn't work for me. Maybe you could use an implementation of the [Lagrange multipliers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=lagrange+multipliers).